# Can I insert date and time with AM/PM to DATE datatype?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

```
INSERT INTO OFFICE VALUES( 23,TO_DATE('07-Jan-2018 12:30 AM', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI TT'),'Meadow Fair');
```

Error report -
ORA-01821: date format not recognized

```
Name         Null?    Type          
------------ -------- ------------- 
OFF_NO       NOT NULL NUMBER(8)     
OFF_DATETIME NOT NULL DATE          
OFF_LOCATION NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
```

I can't change the datatype. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message, says, your date format is incorrect. It should be

```
'DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI AM'
```

See the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#BABEFHFG) for the format elements. For example:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('07-Jan-2018 12:30 AM', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI AM')
FROM dual
```

Output:

```
2018-01-07T00:30:00Z
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! I get it now. But now I'm trying to use this update query.

Comment: UPDATE OFFICE 
SET prod_code = (select prod_code from product where prod_description = 'No more available')
where TO_DATE(off_datetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI AM') = '07-Jan-2020  07:07 AM';

Comment: I get this error: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: @Emma you should probably be testing it the other way around: `where off_datetime = TO_DATE('07-Jan-2020 07:07 AM', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI AM')`